# Crete a method to replace salesforce keywords in json

Tags: apex, json

I am creating a generic method which accepts json string as input parameter and replaces keywords of salesforce present in json. After replacing all the keywords I am returning the modified json string. Also while replacing the word i should ignore case sensitivity. One more requirement is that it should only replace the properties of json i.e it should only replace words on LHS. The following is the code which I have tried but its only possible in JSON.deserializePretty

```
public String replaceWords(){
    String json = '{'+
    '    \"member\": {'+
    '        \"Id\": 168509468,'+
    '        \"firstName\": \"ERIN\",'+
    '        \"Number\": \"number\",'+
    '        \"middleInitial\": \"D\",'+
    '        \"phonenumber\": \"abcd\",'+
    '        \"birthDate\": \"1976-06-14\",'+
    '        \"boolean\": false,'+
    '   }'+
    '}';
     String regexFormat = '(?i)^\\s*"{0}"\\s*:';
     String replacementFormat = '"{0}" :';
     String formattedJSON = 
     JSON.serializePretty(JSON.deserializeUntyped(json));
     List<Replace_word__mdt> rdt =[select 
     MasterLabel,DeveloperName,keyword__c,replaceKeyword__c from 
     Replace_word__mdt];
     for(integer i=0;i<rdt.size();i++){
        String regex = String.format(
        regexFormat,
        new List<String> {rdt[i].MasterLabel}
    );

    // Generate our replacement
    String replacement = String.format(
        replacementFormat,
        new List<String> {rdt[i].DeveloperName}
    );
        formattedJSON = formattedJSON.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
```

}
}

The keywords and the new words are stored in custom metadata. I do not want the json to come in pretty print format.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is written to only match at the beginning of a line, using the `^` modifier. If you do not want behavior to change based on the formatting of the JSON, remove that modifier.

You should then be able to remove the deserialize/reserialize step entirely.